# Problema usando PDO::bindParam com nomes de tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sou iniciante na programação e escrevi um código em php para praticar PDO. Porém, tive um problema: quando uso o comando do MySql sem bindParam funciona normalmente. Quando referencio o nome da tabela usando bindParam, a busca retorna nula. Podem me ajudar aqui? Seguem os dois exemplos:

Assim funciona:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql: host=localhost;dbname=dbphp7","root","root");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Assim o resultado da busca é nulo:

```
<?php
$tabela = "tb_usuarios";
$conn = new PDO("mysql: host=localhost;dbname=dbphp7","root","root");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM :tab");
$stmt->bindParam(":tab",$tabela);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: Você não pode usar o `bindParam` assim

Comment: Olá Lucas! Pode esclarecer melhor onde está o problema no bindParam?

Comment: Você só pode usar isso em valores que serão inseridos/atualizados/deletados/lidos no sql, por exemplo: `SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE usuario_id = :usuario_id`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Lucas! Eu li a documentação, mas não entendi que só poderia usar nesse caso.

Comment: @LucasBittencourt faça do seu comentário uma resposta! Isso pode ajudar outras pessoas no futuro :)

Answer (score 1):

Além do comentário do [Lucas Bittencourt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/93508/lucas-bittencourt) explicando que não é possível usar bindParam com nomes de tabelas, encontrei essa pergunta aqui no StackOverFlow onde foi bem explicada essa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter

O meu objetivo era escrever um método que fizesse uma busca por uma tabela X no banco de dados. Uma alternativa ao bindParam é escrever uma string fora do "prepare" concatenando a variável com o nome da tabela escolhida e depois enviar o comando do MySql pronto por essa string através de uma variável. Algo como:

```
<?php

class Sql extends PDO {    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("mysql: host=localhost;dbname=dbphp7","root","root");
    }    
    public function buscaTabela($comandoSql) {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($comandoSql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($results);
    }    
}

$tabela = "tb_usuarios";
$comandoSql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tabela;
$busca = new Sql;
$busca->buscaTabela($comandoSql)

?>
```

Agradeço a ajuda e espero ajudar alguém com a mesma dúvida.